# Different Code : Delimiter // and Delimiter $$

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cmd

I want to ask you about Stored Procedure. I had tried Delimiter in `MySQL version 5.5.16`. I used to

```
|   DELIMITER //
|   CREATE PROCEDURE Name_Procedure(IN PARAMETER type_data(max_character))
|-> BEGIN
|-> STATEMENT SQL
|-> END //
|   DELIMITER ;
```

Otherwise, in forum change the `// (double blackslash)` with `$$ (double dollar)` but I haven't try this before...

```
|   DELIMITER $$
|   CREATE PROCEDURE Name_Procedure(IN PARAMETER type_data(max_character))
|-> BEGIN
|-> STATEMENT SQL
|-> END $$
|   DELIMITER ;
```

Have you know what the different of `//` and `$$` from mysql version might be?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter. You can specify whichever delimiter you prefer, it does not depend on the version of mysql. I don't know what you're talking about when you say "in forums they change the delimiter" but maybe in some text engines the "//" is already used by something else, so they replace it automatically.